# Understanding DynamoDB throttling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

Context:
Each partition on the table can serve up to 3,000 read request units or 1,000 write request units, or a linear combination of both. If the traffic to a partition exceeds this limit, then the partition might be throttled.

Testing:
I have a table with On-demand capacity having multiple partition keys so I took one key containing 100k records and performed the update operation using batchWrite api using AWS JAVA SDK

Average item size is 262.99 bytes

Test 1:

- Create batch(25 items in batch) and immediately perform the batchWrite

```
final DynamoDBQueryExpression<itemSchema> expression = createDynamoDBQueryExpression(s3Path);
do {
    QueryResultPage<itemSchema> queryPage = mapper.queryPage(itemSchema.class, expression);
    List<itemSchema> itemSchema =  queryPage.getResults();

    for (itemSchema record : itemSchema) {
            record.setField1("Update");
            itemSchemaTableWriteItems.add(record);

            if (itemSchemaTableWriteItems.size()==25) {
                batchWrite(itemSchemaTableWriteItems);
                itemSchemaTableWriteItems = new ArrayList<>();
            }
    }
    expression.setExclusiveStartKey(queryPage.getLastEvaluatedKey());
} while (expression.getExclusiveStartKey() != null);
```

Test 2:

- Create batches (25 items in batch * 20 batches = 500 items * 2 WCU (delete and write) = 1000 write capacity) and perform the batchWrite
- sleep for 1 sec

```
final DynamoDBQueryExpression<itemSchema> expression = createDynamoDBQueryExpression(s3Path);
do {
    QueryResultPage<itemSchema> queryPage = mapper.queryPage(itemSchema.class, expression);
    List<itemSchema> itemSchema =  queryPage.getResults();

    for (itemSchema record : itemSchema) {
            record.setField1("Update");
            itemSchemaTableWriteItems.add(record);

            if (itemSchemaTableWriteItems.size() == 25) {
                listAll.add(itemSchemaTableWriteItems);
                if (listAll.size() == 20) {
                    for (List<itemSchema> item : listAll) {
                        batchWrite(item);
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    listAll = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                itemSchemaTableWriteItems = new ArrayList<>();
            }
    }
    expression.setExclusiveStartKey(queryPage.getLastEvaluatedKey());
} while (expression.getExclusiveStartKey() != null);
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the 2nd test, I'm only writing 1k write requests per second but i still observed throttling. Can you help me understand this?

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/on-demand-table-throttling-dynamodb/

Comment: did you read the rest of the page you linked to?   Show the code you are using.

Comment: @Charles 1) yes. Can you point the statement i missed? 2) Updated above.